# invoke function just after user login in django

Tags: django, django-signals, django-login

I was looking for a way to invoke a function `(do_something)` just after user logged-in.

```
def do_something(request):
    # do blah-blah
    return data
```

One way of doing is that I can check the referrer page using `META['HTTP_REFERER']` if it comes through `'login'` page or not.

But it doesn't make strong criteria if the page comes from any where else.

Is there any `post_login_signal` which can help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) signal.

Answer (score -2):

Create your own log in function. Something like [the Django documentation example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login):

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Do what you want to do here
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Comment: Your answer only applies in case that he can change login function. The right thing here is use user_loggded_in.